# UITextField user interaction issue in Adhoc application iOs

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution, user-interaction

I have created an iPhone app and created it's AdHoc installation file (.ipa) using XCode 4.5, iOs6. And I have installed the app on my device successfully via iTunes.

The issue is, the app has one Login page and Sign Up page, which contains UITextFields. In the login page it created via IB but in sign up page it is through code and added as subview of UIScrollView.
In both the pages everything is working fine. But after the adhoc installation, I opened the sign up page and clicked on any textfield, it is selected and I could enter the value. But after that, I am not able to select any of the textfields in the sign up page. I dismissed the sign up page, then the textfields in the login page also not working.

It is only happening for adhoc installed app. Is there any possible reason for this issue?

Please help.

**Issue update**

I tried to track the issue using Product>Profile>Automation. When I tested through it I got the same issue. At the same time it is working fine when it run from code. Does it help someone to give me some hints?

Comment: does it work well on the simulator? does it work well on debug builds running on the device?

Comment: Yes, it works fine on both conditions and issue is only with the adhoc build.

Comment: just to clarify, your textfields are not firing the delegate methods when selected, but your scroll view scrolls?

Comment: Yes, in the adhoc build, first time any of the textfields can be selected, also can enter the values. Then not able to select any other text field. In the same time, scroll view scrolls. And also Keyboard is not returning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you properly check the delegate methods for UITextField? Ensure that it properly calls its delegate method at the end of editing. From your explanation, I understand that, you could select and enter values in the first text box. So, at the end of editing it should return YES.

Comment: thank you so much, you said it. I forgot to add return YES in endEditing method. But I wonder why it was working when I run through code. Anyway now it is working fine. Thanks again :)